# How to do a delete on cascade using linq to entities?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using the Northwind database to learn linq to entities and the entity framework. I'm trying to delete a Supplier entity using its ID. But in order to do that I have to delete all the entities related to it. Is there a feature in Entity framework that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity framework's cascade delete ability [is dependent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx) on cascade delete correctly set on the relation in the database. Cascade delete in EF works this way:

- You must configure cascade delete in database so that child entities which **are not loaded** to the context are property deleted before parent entity
- You must configure cascade delete in EF so that child entities which **are loaded** to the context are properly deleted before parent entity

Comment: thx for the answer. In fact i configured the database and the delete worked.